# Downloaded files using WebClient.DownloadFile() do not work

Tags: c#, winforms

So I've been trying to download a file from MediaFire using WebClient.DownloadFile(), but all files I download do not work properly. I've tried to download PDF files and PNG files, none of them open correctly in their respective software. I'm using this for a WinForms desktop application. I've already searched for multiple solutions but none of them apply to my situation.

This is the code I've used:

```
private void downloadFile(string url, string filename)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFile(url, filename);          
        }
```

I'm a begginer so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you opened one of those files in a text/hex editor? What does it contain? -- Try Notepad first. -- There's the chance that you get the a download link, a compressed file or text that contains an error description. A link to an existing, accessible resource would make testing easier.

Comment: BTW, very often this kind of sites require that you set a `User-Agent` header. -- You should also specify the .Net version in use and the System where this code is tested (or, if you code in Windows 10, if you need to also support Windows 7).

Comment: It looks like opening the png files in a text editor shows the html code of the page I tried to download the file from. The PDF does resemble the original file but there must be a difference somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself with some help from [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi).
I needed to find the link the page was using for the download process, not the link to the page itself. I did this by accessing the code of the page using the inspect tool and finding the direct link to the file, then using my previous method it worked just fine.